# SwiftUI, using ForEach's argument causing error "Unable to infer closure type"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a simple View struct, in which there's an array of `AnyView`. In `body` I try to loop over the array with a `ForEach`.

```
struct TestView<Content>: View where Content : View
{
    var Cells: [AnyView] = []

    init<Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID, Item: View>(
        @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
        where Content == ForEach<Data, ID, Item>
    {
        let Views = content()
        Cells = Views.data.map { AnyView(Views.content($0)) }
    }

    func test(_ i: UInt) -> CGPoint
    {
        return CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    }

    func test() -> CGPoint
    {
        return CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<self.Cells.count, id: \.self) {i in
                Text("").position(self.test(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However at compilation it gives an error on the `ForEach` line: “Unable to infer closure type in the current context”. What causes this error?

Note that I have 2 definitions of `test()`. If I use the one with no argument, the error goes away. (why...?) Also if I replace `self.Cells.count` with a constant number (like "10"), the error also goes away.

I’m using Xcode 11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that test's parameter is a `UInt`, while `0..<self.Cells.count`'s type is `Range<Int>`, so `i` is inferred by the compiler to be an `Int`. When you pass it into the function, the function is expecting a `UInt`, and the compiler cannot implicitly cast from `Int` to `UInt`, so you have to do it. Here is one way to do that:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ForEach(0..<self.Cells.count, id: \.self) { i in
            Text("").position(self.test(UInt(exactly: i) ?? 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to fix your problem is to just change the test function's parameter to be of type `Int` and deal with casting to `UInt` inside of there if you really need to have it be a `UInt` and not just an `Int`.